Are the site rules going to be consistently enforced, or should we just give up on this site?
miracles - Can God heal someone bedridden with late-stage Alzheimer's disease?
is the latest example of a question that:

is blatantly inappropriate for the site.
has received some votes to be closed.
receives answers from people with high reputations.

Previous posts, such as:

Brothers, we are not Christians‼ - Christianity Meta Stack Exchange
Another reason this is not a Christian site - Christianity Meta Stack Exchange
Why can't I ask for personal advice? - Christianity Meta Stack Exchange
Should we say we are a 'secular website'? - Christianity Meta Stack Exchange
Proposal: Change our masthead to read: "about CHRISTIANITY" - Christianity Meta Stack Exchange

make it clear that this isn't supposed to happen.
Yet it continues to happen, and no one does anything about it.
If the rules aren't going to be followed or enforced (or enforced for some users and not for others), the site should make an official announcement that it is now a free-for-all.

While there still may be some blatant questions that aren't being closed, I don't think that is one of them... I've never heard of a Christian denomination that says God is unable to do miracles.

The recent "closed due to philosophy" one irks me.... especially when things like "God can do miracles right?" questions are there. The one about how christians should respond to secular philosophy stuff is apologetics and actually is an academic subject.

Okay... so now philosophy is okay? starts reciting a prayer for patience

The Moderators face a very difficult task on SE-C. It is on a platform which is secular, yet we are permitted to discuss 'Christianity' in an academic way.
But allowances must be made for the fact that many attending the site wish, also, to express themselves in a spiritual way.
Steering a path through all this is not simple. And I do not think this particular situation deserves the blanket criticism ('blatantly inappropriate') which is expressed above.
The question in point can be considered from different aspects ; decisions were taken by voluntary consensus and by Moderation. Not all will agree with that consensus, nor are they obliged to agree with it.
We are a consensus of voting individuals and we elect our own Moderators.
And we also, sometimes (perhaps) make well-meaning mistakes. By which we learn.
Which is permissible ; for to err is human but to forgive is Divine.

Is the question in question blatantly inappropriate for the site?
There are three questions within the post given as the latest example.  Here they are, in the order asked:

Can God heal someone bedridden with late-stage Alzheimer's disease?

Do you think if my sister invites people from this church to pray for my aunt, it could make a difference?

is it possible for God to heal someone bedridden with late-stage Alzheimer's disease?


I submit that numbers 1 and 3 are the same and that they are not asking whether God will heal or how to bring healing about but whether God can heal.  As such it is a potential duplicate of this question, What is the Biblical basis for continuationism, but isn't any more or less opinion based or blatantly inappropriate than that or any question regarding the continuationist/cessationist debate.
Question number 2 is a personal opinion/advice type question but it is not the main question.  While much of the background information included in the question is personal in nature it is also fairly obviously given as explanation of why the question has arisen and, as such, can easily be removed (i.e. ignored in the reading).  The answer given takes pains to avoid addressing that question directly.
The other two protests given here are:

has received some votes to be closed.
receives answers from people with high reputations.

Please forgive me if I am wrong but is there a regulation against answering a question which has merely received close votes?  Are the close votes themselves not sometimes opinion-based?

In response to and to inform the claim that "Can God heal...?" and "Is it possible for God to heal ...?" are close-worthy truth/opinion questions, I have just asked Is there a Christian denomination that teaches that God cannot heal?

I've always wanted a path for us to scope specifically non-denominational questions, but I really don't know how to do it.  I guess we could make a tag for [tag:ask-mike]

The two questions, "Can God heal" and "Is it possible for God" are truth questions, and "Do you think" is directly soliciting opinion. I'm not saying they aren't good questions and don't deserve answers; I'm saying they are blatantly inappropriate for this site, and that the answer is even more inappropriate for this site. (Compare with an auto mechanics site asking for restaurant recommendations along a specific route.) ¶ A good answer would have explained why the question doesn't belong here, and would have provided links to other sites where such questions are appropriate.

@PeterTurner  Very funny but please don't (aka James 3:1) :)!  Seriously, though, isn't non-denominational a sort of denomination akin to the independent  Baptists in that they are fully autonomous?  Evangelical could/should be a tag also (but that's another question).

@RayButterworth if you preface the question with "according to the Catholic Church, can God heal Alzheimer's" then you're OK - but I don't understand non-denominational churches enough to say whether "according to a non-denominal church that believes in faith healing can God heal Alzheimer's" - but you're right - the problem is the solicitation of opinion, makes it clear the question is not about non-denomination Christians unless he's asking them if they're liars. I do agree with the closing of the question, I just don't know what the appropriate way would be to get make it on topic.

@RayButterworth Strong disagree.  Compare with an auto mechanics site asking if the engine can be fixed.  I suggest this question and the answer you offered to it are a better example of what you are criticizing: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/92080/47250

When I see a question that has a title like "does God" or "can God" or "why does God" etc... I usually go and mod-hammer close them, but that doesn't do much for the likability of the site either.  They're usually real questions - just not academic questions which is a bummer because it would be nice, occasionally, to attract new users and keep people curious about Christianity engaged.
So, I'm not saying we're not trying to be consistent, but I do think we're trying to be nice - which is usually better than consistent. I've parented teenagers as long as I've been a moderator on this site and I'm learning a lot about the power of words to shut off conversations and put up blockers - these are obstacles to growing in faith which we have a higher duty, than our duty as moderators, to avoid.
And to all of the question answerers

Not many of you should become teachers, my fellow believers, because you know that we who teach will be judged more strictly.
James 3:1

is pretty scary when you think of how many views your posts could potentially get when you've been answering questions here a long time.  Especially if you're answering a question like "Why does God..."

I agree with the James 3:1 thing, I answer questions with moderate inner terror and responsibility within. I agree with most of the closing of questions.

Yes, being a moderator can't be easy. ¶ Most of these highly subjective questions have an objective question hiding in them.  Giving suggestions for improvement in the comments sometimes helps (that's the purpose of comments), but not always.  Ideally, someone would then rewrite the question in a proper form, but that would require significant work, and it can hardly be dumped into the moderators' workload.
